# RTMPS protocol c#/vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, rtmps

does anyone has a clue how the RTMPS-Protocoll works? I haven't found any source code, documentation or libraries for vb.net/c# on the web!
I read somewhere that it's only a TCP connection, but is this right?
If yes, how can I use this?

Could you pleas provide me source code, a library or a documentation?
Thanks in advance!

--
coolerfarmer

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RTMPdump](http://lkcl.net/rtmp/) I used to work with it a while back so I don't know how well it has been maintained in the mean time. However be sure to have a look at the [clean-room specification](http://lkcl.net/rtmp/RTMPE.txt). I used that document as a starting point to implement my own RTMPS protocol, however I wasn't able to ever finish it.

On a personal note, I would recommend using C# or even C++ to implement a client, if you know those languages as well as vb.net

Comment: yeah, I mainly use c#!  Thanks for the answer! I'll take a look at that!